# Mac OS doesn't resolve address in hotspot shared with create-ap in raspberry pi

Tags: macos, raspberry-pi

I have created a hotspot with [creat-ap](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap) on raspberry pi, I can connect to the shared hotspot,
I set two addresses on raspberry pi but MAC OS can't resolve the URL, 
surprisingly I have no problem with other OS's like Linux or Windows
when I add URL and IP's manually on MAC it works

Comment: What do you mean by *"macOS can't resolve the URL"*? The URL of what?

Comment: I use the raspberry pi as a server and run a local web-app on that, I set specific URL to reach to web-app like [link](http://test.in)

Comment: I am confused. Your title says your Mac doesn't connect, but the first line of your question says you can connect?

Comment: sry for that, MAC can connect to hotspot but can't resolve addresses